# Как избежать O(n^2) C#

Tags: c#, массивы, unity3d

нужно замерить расстояние между всеми точками массива и найти все соседние для каждой из них, как можно это сделать не используя вложенный цикл?

```
            foreach (var joint in joints)
            {
                foreach (var jointNext in joints)
                {
                    if (joint == jointNext) continue;
                    if((jointNext.Position - joint.Position).magnitude <= _jointsConnectDistance)
                    {
                        TwoWayConnetion(joint, jointNext);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Что "это"? И что такое "O(O(n))"?

Comment: Если вам нужно расстояния между всеми то эн квадрат никак не избежать. Возможно лишь какие-то частные случаи, например если у вас массивы отсортированы и вам не точные значение нужны, а какая-то метрика не превышающая заданную величину -- тогда можно останавливать обсчёт т.к. дальше считать нет смысла.

Answer (score 6):

Предлагаю оптимизацию, которая хорошо работает для хороших наборов точек.

Разбейте всю плоскость или пространство где живут ваши точки квадратной или кубической решёткой. Шаг решётки `_jointsConnectDistance`. Каждая точка помещается в корзину соответствующую квадрату или кубу куда она попадает. Координаты квадрата или куба - это кортеж целых чисел. По ним удобно размещать точки в `HashMap`.

Когда `HashMap` готов, пробегаете по его корзинам. Точки из корзины надо сравнивать только с точками из той же корзины и её восемью или двадцатью шестью соседками.

Если расстояние заранее не известно или вы хотите использовать разные расстояние для разных точек, используйте [K-d дерево](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE).

Answer (score 1):

Если под `найти соседние` вы имеете ввиду это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То `это` называется `триангуляция`.

Есть разные фигуры: `convex`, `concave` с дырками.
Алгоритмы триангуляции не просты.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
*Triangulation Delaunay*

Поищите готовые фреймворки триангуляции для C#.

Comment: Диаграмма Вороного (которая соседка триангуляции Делоне) годится для поиска точек ближайших к данной. Задача называется все ближайшие пары. ТС решает другую задачу - найти все точки ближе фиксированного расстояния.